# Storing the input from a Text Field in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to invoke the method `delImg` when the button delete is called. I used the following code segment for it. But the method parameters are highlighted as wrong. I used Tkinter.How to correct it ?

```
import Tkinter
import sys
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename
root= Tk()

enText =StringVar()

#root.geometry("400*400+500+300")
root.title("Welcome")


def Hello():
 mtext = enText.get()
 mlabel2 = Label(root,text=mtext).pack()
 print(mtext)
 return mtext

def callback():
 name= askopenfilename()
 print name
 return name

def delImg(m1,n1):
 if(m1!=n1):
    print("Error")

text = Entry(root,textvariable =enText).pack()
mbtn = Button(root,text="Enter",command=callback,fg='red').pack()
mbtn = Button(root,text="Ok",command=Hello,fg='red').pack()
mbtn = Button(root,text="Delete", command= lambda:          

delImg(mtext,name),fg='red').pack()


#print(mtext)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're missing a `(` in one of your lines.  I would expect you want this: `delImg((mtext,name),fg='red').pack()`.  Is that just a typo here, or is it like that in your original code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`mtext`** and **`name`** variables exist only in the scope of `Hello` and `Callback` functions, respectively.

This means that even though you do have an `mtext` variable, it is inside the `Hello` function, and you cannot access it from outside the function itself.

There's two ways to get it to global scope — one is to use define these variables as global somewhere in the code (`global mtext`) or just call the function in the outside scope, and assign the return value to a new variable you'll use with the `delImg` function.

Comment: Thank you very much